# MySQL Warning #1292 in nested select statement causes wrong behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mariadb

I am trying to use this nested select statement:

```sql
select  e.*  from app_entity_31 e  
    where e.id in (
        select field_272 from app_entity_26 as f where f.id = 4
    );
```

The nested select is supposed to return `(1,3,4)`. Unfortunately, MySQL apparently believes this to be a decimal value and throws a warning `#1292 truncated wrong decimal value: '1,3,4'.`

The query then behaves as if I input 1. I tried `select CAST(field_272 as CHAR)` - same result.
When I run the inner select by itself, it correctly outputs (1,3,4)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please publish table definitions and sample data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] e.*  
FROM app_entity_31 AS e  
JOIN app_entity_26 AS f ON FIND_IN_SET(e.id, f.field_272)
WHERE f.id = 4;
```

But I'd recommend you to normalize your `app_entity_26` table instead, and store only one `id` value per row.

Comment: Maybe a subquery with `exists` would avoid the need for `distinct`

Comment: @GMB This is possible. What is optimal? must be tested - the execution time may both be the same and differ twice or even more to any side, depends on the data statistic.